# New Service endpoint

Tags: azure-devops

I am following along the tutorial with SmartHotel360 and trying to set it up.  In the README.md, it says 'In VSTS, navigate to Services by clicking on the gear icon...' and this is to create a new service endpoint.  Where is this done?  What is VSTS?  Visual Studio Team Server?  Do I first make a branch of the SmartHotel360 and open this in Visual Studio? What if I am using one email account to access the code where the tasks are assigned and another email to complete the courses? Does this make a difference?

I guess my question is, where is this VSTS?  Is this where I view the SmartHotel360 code?

Comment: I guess VSTS is now Azure DevOps, why can't they just say Azure DevOps in the tutorial?

Comment: I think you are using a very, very, and yes, very old tutorial :) but the thing is, it says very clearly in big bold letters that the project you are looking at is archived. So, why would you be using that.

Comment: @Keenan Stewart Not get your latest information, is the below answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Thanks @HughLin-MSFT... Sorry,  have to come back to this later.  I wanted to do the tutorials/lessons/tasks in the SmartHotel360, but I had issues setting this up.  I will try again later.  I think I only need to download all of the projects and then I can do the tasks, but I was wondering if I can do this with Azure DevOps, although the tutorial mentions VSTS.  I can investigate more of this later when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps Services was formerly named Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) -- rebranded as Azure DevOps in 2018. So the tutorial you followed should be before 2018.

The github README.md about SmartHotel360(like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/SmartHotel360-Website)) are retired, archived, and no longer supported. For the latest sample references please visit: https://aka.ms/tailwindtraders & https://aka.ms/rpsls

To interact with Azure, you'll need to create a Service Endpoint in Azure DevOps. This endpoint includes the authentication information required to deploy to Azure. This [document](https://github.com/microsoft/TailwindTraders/tree/master/Documents/DemoScripts/Integrating%20Azure%20DevOps%2C%20Microsoft%20Teams%20and%20GitHub#configuring-service-endpoint-in-azure-devops) gives a guide to configure Service Endpoint in Azure DevOps, please refer to it.